# How to work with Android SQLite Database with 2 table relate together?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am coding follow this tutorial http://www.9android.net/how-to-code-android-sqlite/ 
for work with android sqlite database. but it's just has one table, in my case, i have 2 table which relate together by 1 field
one is: class_table: class_id(PK), class_name;
one is: student_table: student_id(PK), class_id(FK), student_name
how to CRUD into these 2 table with SQLite database code.
please send me the sample source. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since your queries may involve multiple tables, your best bet is to use [rawquery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29). In this way you can provide sqllite queries and fetch the results the same way you perform joins on dbmss.

Comment: i still dont undertand how to work with sqlite when i have more than 2 table which be related together. do you have sample source or someone similar tutorial?

Comment: I guess you can check this link: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/01/creating-multiple-sqlite-database.html

Comment: it just show how to create new tables, not show me how to work with CRUD sqlite.